# How to get the current frame in a live stream with python and opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am doing some real-time Computer vision work, like a live stream detection.

The part of detection takes about 0.3s / frame.
But the video FPS is higher, maybe 15 or 30 FPS.

So, In my work now, I use

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp url")
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

to get the first frame, and then after detection process I'll get the new frame and detect.

But the detection process took about 0.3s,

So how do I get the current frame after I done the detection(0.3s)?

Not the frame just after I had detected.

Comment: You can try to wait the thread that captures the frames for 0.3 seconds and start it again after 0.3 seconds. Assuming your application is multi threaded

Comment: You're getting the current frame, are you not? `VideoCapture` is not storing images anywhere, so you can access them after your detection is done. `VideoCapture` is reading the data that is being written to the port specified in the URL, at the time of reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello sir as i understand your question can be explained as follow.

1. Open video link (which have 15 FPS or 30 FPS)
2. Read last frame (X) and save into current frame
3. Send current frame (X) to detection process
4. Keep reading so current frame become (X + t) (t > 1)
5. When detection process is finish, send the current frame (X + t)

I think your problem is that currently, the detection process is blocking your main process. This make the current frame is not (X + t) but instead (X + 1) .

So you have 2 options here:

1. Separate you video capturing process and detection process so each process can run without blocking each other. This one is very hard
2. DO NOT separate video capturing process and detection process. Instead set the position of next reading frame. This on is easy. The document of video is at : https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c

   1. calculate the next frame position

      t = ....
   2. set the frame position

   cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, t)

   3. then read

   ret, frame = cap.read()

Hope that help